# 2 divs floating left inside a div. 2 of such divs floating left inside another div - height issue

Tags: html, css, height, css-float

So I have this kind of a structure:

```
<!-- Mind Wrap  -->
<div class="mid-wrap">

<!-- Content Wrap  -->
<div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="left-sidebar"></div>
    <div class="main-article"> </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<!-- Right siebar -->
<div class="right-sidebar"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

My Css is as follows:

```
    .mid-wrap {
    width:700px;
    height:auto;
    }

    .content-wrap {
    width:500px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    }

    .right-sidebar {
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    }

    .left-sidebar {
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    }

    .main-article {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    }
.clear {
clear:both;
}
```

Now, when the content inside the div "main-article" goes longer than the right sidebar, the height is not automatically adjusted. Instead, there's a massive overflow which overlaps my footer. Is there some protocol to be followed for such "nested" floating elements. Or have I used `clear:both;` the wrong way?

Thanks in advance

----- UPDATE -------

Alright, here's my page link:
http://www.currentconservation.org/new/?q=featured

It's on drupal, so some people might find it annoying to go through all the html. But the page basically has the same structure as I've mentioned, with other nested divs inside the respective divs.

As you can see, the footer is completely out of place.

Comment: did you try overflow:hidden on parent div? instead of clearing floated elements

Comment: Based on your posted HTML and CSS, everything seems to work.  See http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/XpQFV/  You did not post the footer code so you may have something else going on that you have not show in your code.

Comment: I think you want to this http://jsfiddle.net/RVH8D/7/

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? I made one ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/sA2Fk/1/)), but it doesn't seem to have the problem.

Comment: Aw, I typed too slowly.

Comment: I've updated with a link. If that's too much work, I'll post the footer code. I don't think there's a problem with the footer though. Can't imagine how it could be?

Comment: use min-height rather than height

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use a lot of `<div class="clear"></div>` on your HTML pages.
Here is an example on how to force an element to self-clear  :

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
```

**Notice:** Apply a `class="clearfix"` to the parent element.

Comment: Did you see a problem with the original code? I think it works fine even if the method of clearing is not the best.

Comment: There is no problem in the original code, is just a suggestion of clean solution to forcing element without adding lot of div.clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!-- Mind Wrap  -->
    <div class="mid-wrap">

    <!-- Content Wrap  -->
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="left-sidebar"></div>
        <div class="main-article"> </div>
       <!-- Right sidebar -->
    <div class="right-sidebar"></div>
    </div> 
    </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

place clear div just above the footer